# Android filter, change drawable color

Tags: java, android, image, layout, imagefilter

So, I want to apply a filter to an image in Android, this image is all green but with different tones of this color and I want to make it red. Right now I'm using this code:

```
Drawable ballon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.msg_out);
        ballon.setColorFilter(new
                PorterDuffColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.redLightClose), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));

view.setBackgroundDrawable(ballon);
```

But as a result I get a brownish mix of both colors... Should I use another kind of filter? If so, witch one would you recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Tint instead and it did the job.

```
Drawable iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.msg_out);
            DrawableCompat.setTint(iconDrawable, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
            setBackgroundViewCompat(text, iconDrawable);
```